# Get Javascript to apply to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently the javascript here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready
 $('myimage').addpowerzoom()
})
</script>
```

Only works for a id="myimage"

How can I make it work for a class="myimage"

It references a .js file, do I need to make changes there? I just downloaded a zoom javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: `$('myimage')` is supposed to work only for tags named 'myimage', i.e. `<myimage/>`. Are you sure, its working for elements with `id=myimage` ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5):

jQuery selectors are just like CSS selectors.

Although your original selector shouldn't work at all, you can prefix it with a dot and it *should* work:

```
$('.myimage').addpowerzoom();
```